# Venmo option not shown in Braintree Dropin on iOS

Tags: ios, braintree, venmo

The braintree dropin ui IOSv4 does not show the venmo payment option even though I followed the configuration docs at https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/venmo/client-side/ios/v4.
Other payment options are shown and functional.
I don't have the venmo app installed on the device, because on android it simply defaults to a webview if the app isn't installed so I assumed iOS would do the same.
Now, however, after looking at the code I see this:

```
 if (isVenmoAppInstalled || [BTDropInOverrides displayVenmoOption]) {
                [activePaymentOptions addObject:@(BTUIKPaymentOptionTypeVenmo)];
 }
```

The docs don't specify this, so I thought I'd ask for help here.

I launch the drop-in ui like this:

```
BTDropInRequest *request = [[BTDropInRequest alloc] init];
BTDropInController *dropIn = [[BTDropInController alloc] initWithAuthorization:clientTokenOrTokenizationKey request:request handler:^(BTDropInController * _Nonnull controller, BTDropInResult * _Nullable result, NSError * _Nullable error) {
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you added the Venmo subspec to your Podfile? Curious if that [enables Venmo in the Drop-in UI](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/venmo/client-side/ios/v4#enable-venmo-for-drop-in) for you. Otherwise, it may be best to try downloading the Venmo app since you'll need the app for when the [app switching occurs](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/venmo/client-side/ios/v4#setup-for-app-switch).

Comment: Yes I have. I was under the assumption that if the app wasn't installed it would use a webview. That's how it works for paypal...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately right now the venmo icon does not appear in simulator. If you run on an actual device, it should be there.